# How to use glass shader to my house model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have been working on ThreeJS for a while, i tried to load a house model using OBJ + MTL loader, now i need to apply glass shaders for window materials

i managed to load the model successfully by

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'new/' );
                mtlLoader.setPath( 'new/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'House.mtl', function( materials ) {
                    materials.preload();
                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.setPath( 'new/' );
                    objLoader.load( 'House.obj', function ( object ) {
                        object.position.y = - 5;
                        object.scale.x=object.scale.y=object.scale.z=0.05
                        object.castShadow = true;
                        object.receiveShadow = true;
                        object.traverse( function( node ) { if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { node.castShadow = true;
                                       node.receiveShadow = true; } } );
                        mesh = object;
                        scene.add( mesh );

                    });
                });
```

Now i would like to add glass shaders for house windows in this model, in which way should i code, how can i take the reference from loaded house to make a shader ?
Any other way to code glass shader ?